# Read line by line from Website

Tags: c#, php, web

I have a website (php) with two lines.

I try to read the content with following code:

```
var url = "WEBSITE.php";
var client = new WebClient();

using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the string "line" contains not one line of the two lines. It contains the whole content with 
 tags...is it possible to fetch line by line? or have i to delimit it by myself?

Thanks!

Comment: well, what's a "line" in this case? one line of text displayed in a browser could be many hundreds of lines of html. the remote server may not be set up (or disallows) byte serving, and just sends the entire document regardless of what byte range you request.

Comment: View source in browser. Maybe the server is returning the whole file as one line.

Comment: Look at HTML parsers like HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: one line is seperated via br in html.

Comment: Lol. `<br>` separates the lines in rendered HTML. When you're reading the file you're just reading a text file.  What you need to do is in your echos add a `\n` like `echo "<br><input />"` change to `echo "\n<br><input />"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that a little bit easier by using something like this:

```
string url = "WEBSITE.php";
string content = WebClient.DownloadString(url);

foreach (string line in content.Split(new string[] { "<br>", "</br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    // Do something with each "line" ;-)
}
```